# Restore MAMP configs post upgrade

Tags: apache, mamp, mamp-pro

I just upgraded MAMP and lost my old httpd.conf file. Was this moved or archived somewhere? or am I SOL for getting it back?

Answer (score 0):

Not even going to mark this as the official "answer" since its only partial, but for my case I needed some env vars back. I noticed a few MAMP backup directories in `/Applications/` with the naming convention `/Applications/MAMP_{YYYY-MM-DD_TT-TT-TT}/` where the name is appended with the date and time of the original upgrade.

Great! but for some reason the httpd.conf is empty. I was able to dig around and find what I needed for my case in bin/envvars, but its very strange my .conf was wiped out. Is this a security thing?